# How to check if element is included in array with arduino?

Tags: c, arrays, arduino

I have an array called numbers and I want to test if a certain number is included in that array.

```
void loop(){
  if (arrayIncludeElement(numbers, mynumber)){
    // Do something
  } else {
    // Do something else
  }
}
```

I have written a version of the *arrayIncludeElement* function, but it don't seem to work.

```
boolean arrayIncludeElement(array, element) {
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(array); i++) {
    if (array[i] == element) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

**ERROR MESSAGES**

- sketch:5: error: 'array' was not declared in this scope
- sketch:5: error: 'element' was not declared in this scope
- sketch:5: error: initializer expression list treated as compound
  expression
- sketch:3: error: redefinition of 'boolean arrayIncludeElement'
- sketch:5: error: 'boolean arrayIncludeElement' previously defined
  here
- sketch.ino: In function 'void loop()':
- sketch:11: error: 'arrayIncludeElement' cannot be used as a function
- sketch.ino: At global scope:
- sketch:16: error: redefinition of 'boolean arrayIncludeElement'
- sketch:5: error: 'boolean arrayIncludeElement' previously defined
  here
- sketch:16: error: 'array' was not declared in this scope
- sketch:16: error: 'element' was not declared in this scope

**EDIT**
I updated the function to this.

```
boolean arrayIncludeElement(int array[], int element);
boolean arrayIncludeElement(int array[], int element) {
  for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(array)/4); i++) {
    if (array[i] == element) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

But now I get this error

- sketch.ino: In function 'void loop()':
- sketch:8: error: 'arrayIncludeElement' was not declared in this scope
- sketch:10: error: expected `;' before '}' token

**Line 8** being this

```
if (arrayIncludeElement(numbers, 5){
```

and **Line 10** being this

```
} else {
```

Comment: Shouldn't you specify the *types* for your function arguments?

Comment: Also, `sizeof(array)` wouldn't work in your function -- you need to pass the size separately.

Comment: The `sizeof(array)` works alright. The problem was clearly that I missed the datatypes for arguments to the function.

Comment: No, the `sizeof(array)` gives the number of bytes in a pointer to `int` (or whatever your array is of).  It gives *something*, but not the right thing.

Comment: Okay. But I don't know the length of my array, so is there another approach?

Comment: You'll either have to keep track of the array size, or mark the end with a reserved value (one that you don't consider valid in your array).

Answer (score 1):

You are not mentioning the data type of that arguments. You have to mention the arguments.
Then you have to declare the function prototype.

```
 boolean arrayIncludeElement(int array[], int element);
 boolean arrayIncludeElement(int array[], int element) {
 for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
      if (array[i] == element) {
          return true;
      }
    }
  return false;
 }
```

Edit: As like Dmitri said, pass the no of elements in the array as a function argument.
Don't use the sizeof.

Then declartion of function, must be placed before where it is used. So in this place the function prototype before the function `void loop()`.

Comment: @EmilBonneKristiansen Ok no Problem.

Comment: Remember that inside the function, `array` looks like a pointer -- the type doesn't specify the number of elements.  `sizeof(array)` will give the number of bytes in the pointer, not the number of bytes in the whole array.  He's got to pass the size separately.

Comment: I thought it worked for a moment, but it seems there is a new error.

Comment: Okay, A friend of mine made it work. I feel like I am not really used to this kind of strict programming. I marked this answer as correct, thx everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this question is getting closer to [How do I determine the size of my array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c)

BUT, in the general case, you do have to provide the length of the array or use some guard element (like null-terminated strings). Somewhere up the call chain you must know the size of the array, don't you?

A small example to show why sizeof() may not be correct:

```
int size_test(char b[])
{
    char a[10];
    char foo[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
    char *bar = malloc(20);
    printf("sizeof a = %ld, sizeof b = %ld, sizeof foo = %ld, sizeof bar = %ld\n", sizeof(a), sizeof(b), sizeof(foo), sizeof(bar));
}
int main()
{
    char b[12];
    size_test(b);
}
```

which, on my (64 bit) machine, prints

`sizeof a = 10, sizeof b = 8, sizeof foo = 5, sizeof bar = 8`